# Table with no primary foreign key match

Tags: database, key, primary-key

Is it possible to have a table in a database that has no primary foreign key match up?

The table will be holding file paths to particular files and directories that I want to upload which doesn't relate to any of the other tables in the database. Is this good practise or should all tables have a primary foreign key match up? If so should I create a separate database with just this table?

Comment: there's no compulsion to have primary, foreign keys in your tables, and as you said there will be no relation to other tables it is completely fine, you can also join tables even if you do not have primary, foreign keys

Comment: @Mr.Alien You could post your comment as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every table should have a key but that doesn't mean it has to have a *foreign key* referencing it. The purpose of the key is to ensure that data is uniquely identifiable and guarantee that the expected set of dependencies is enforced.